# Session unset function not working

Tags: php, html

I have made this code(it is a part of my whole script) --

```
if(unset($_SESSION['USER_ID']))
{
     $success_code_array[] = '3111';
     $_SESSION['POPUP_SUCCESS_CODE'] = $success_code_array;
     session_write_close();
     header("Location: ".$_SESIION['PATH']."");
     exit();
}
else
{
     $_SESSION['ERROR_CODE'] = '177';
     session_write_close();
     header("Location: ".$_SESSION['PATH']."error.php");
     exit();
}
```

And error I got --

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_UNSET in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysharepoint\1.1\res\scripts\php\functions\log_out.php on line 21

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error and what could be done to overcome this error?

Comment: Highlight the line 21 in the code ,it will be easy to debug the issue

Comment: `unset()` is not a function, it is a language construct... (see notes in http://lv.php.net/unset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) is void, it doesn't return anything. If this is kind of logout script you probably can destroy the whole session as follows:

```
if(session_destroy()) { ...
```

Of course you should save `$_SESSION['PATH']` somewhere for further usage *before* you destroy the session ...

**EDIT:**

Beware you have also a typo there. It doesn't cause the problem but may save you few minutes later:

```
if(unset($_SESSION['USER_ID']))
{
     $success_code_array[] = '3111';
     $_SESSION['POPUP_SUCCESS_CODE'] = $success_code_array;
     session_write_close();
     header("Location: ".$_SESIION['PATH'].""); // <-- $_SESIION instead of $_SESSION
     exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't unset session but [destroy it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php). That's the proper way to unset it.

Comment: @Jack Billy i'm glad to help you.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel you are right, sorry Jack Billy i've overlooked your code.

Answer (score 0):

unset() returns nothing (void).
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

I'm not sure if the error comes from this but it doesn't make sence using it in an if-statement.